# How can I reference xaml Template from a Converter?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, converters, controltemplate

I am currently stuck on a problem assigning different templates to a control via a converter.

So I have 2 templates.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="_templateA" x:Key="templateA">
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <Blah />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Name="_templateB" x:Key="templateB">
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <Blah Blah />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

and I have this control using this converter:

```
<ControlA x:Name="_controlA" >
     <Control Template="{Binding Converter={StaticResource templateConverters}}" />
</ControlA>
```

My Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Object a;
        ControlTemplate template = null;

        try
        {
            a= value as ObjectA;
            if (value != null)
                template = a.useTemplate1 ? [templateA from xaml] : [templateB from xaml];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
        }

        return toolbar;
    }
```

In my Converter, how am I able to get reference to my xaml file so that it allows me to assign it my desired template???

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Comment: Too many question marks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you should think on some other implementation but here is what you're asking for:

your converter code:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ControlTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public ControlTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    ... Convert methods using TemplateA and TemplateB properties...
}
```

usage in XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- templates with 'templateA' and 'templateB' keys -->
    <Converters:MyConverter x:Key="templateConverters" TemplateA="{StaticResource templateA}" TemplateB="{StaticResource templateB}" />
<UserControl.Resources>

...

<ControlA x:Name="_controlA" >
    <Control Template="{Binding Converter={StaticResource templateConverters}}" />
</ControlA>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I want to try to use data triggers as suggested by another user, but I need to figure out how to get that working. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: I just gave you code which does what you've asked, I believe that maybe some other approach will be more suitable for your situation. Right now it looks a little bit strange because templateConverter doesn't seem to use any value for conversion. In such situation I would think on using TemplateSelector as suggested by Pavlo Glazkov together with ContentControl. DataTriggers suggested by Pavlo seems also to be a good solution, but! only if your condition is simple. If logic is not that simple then I would propose using my code or smth like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is called a Template Selector. You can read about it, for example, here: http://codingbandit.com/Blog/blog/wpf-data-templates-part-4-template-selectors/

Given that, you will be defining a template selector (see ContentTemplateSelector property on your control). And its `SelectTemplate` method will look something like this:

```
public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
{
    ControlTemplate template = null;
    ContentPresenter pres = container as ContentPresenter;

    try
    {
        if (value != null)
            template = item.useTemplate1 ? pres.FindResource("_templateA") : pres.FindResource("_templateB");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
    }

    return toolbar;
}
```

**Update:**
Sorry, I overlooked that you are trying to get a ControlTemplate, while template selectors are for selecting a DataTemplate. But I believe that you task can also be achieved using data templates.

If you still want to use ControlTemplate then triggers is the way to go:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="_templateA" x:Key="templateA">
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
        <Blah />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Name="_templateB" x:Key="templateB">
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
        <Blah Blah />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MyControlStyle" TargetType="[x:Type Control}">
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource templateB}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding useTemplate1}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource templateA}"/>
       </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And you control:

```
<ControlA x:Name="_controlA" >
     <Control Style="{StaticResource MyControlStyle}" />
</ControlA>
```

Comment: Is it possible under "Value" from datatrigger, that i can enter in enumerations instead of a string, cause I want to compare an enumeration. And if the enumeration is A then use templateA, else use B Thanks

Comment: nvm I figured it out thanks. This works also.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/552ce03c-e429-4302-9157-6b7f6247ce06

Comment: Please mark an answer.  You can also use {x:Static YourEnum.YourEnumValue} if you want to use an attribute for Value.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Templates in the resources of some control, give them x:Keys and call:

```
ControlTemplate template = someControl.FindResource("Key") as ControlTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to load the [XAML Resource file from the Application Resource dictionaries as described here](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2010/01/dynamic-controltemplate-in-silverlight.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this better with DataTriggers:

```
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Name="TemplateA" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
            <Blah />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="TemplateB" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
            <Blah Blah />
        </StackPanel>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProp}" Value="1">
          <Setter TargetName="TemplateA" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          <Setter TargetName="TemplateB" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProp}" Value="0">
          <Setter TargetName="TemplateA" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          <Setter TargetName="TemplateB" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    </ControlTemplate>
```

This is off the top of my head, so TargetName might be SourceName, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am not able to get it working with the trigger though, probably i'm not implementing it right. How is the "Value" the value that will be compared to what is being binded, and if it matches, it will use that specific set of code?

Comment: What type is your value?  It will execute the set of Setters when the Value matches.  There can be some weirdness depending on your Value's type.